# how to take a screen shot and send it via MMS?

Tags: mms, screenshots

can I somehow take a screen shot of a google maps in a `easy way` and then send it via MMS?

---

HTC Desire on 2.1 (not rooted)

Answer (score 5):

Only if you're rooted. See this answer: [How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/taking-a-screenshot-of-an-android-phone/1773#1773)

Comment: yep, I read that one. It led  me to ShootMe which works sometimes even on non-rooted phones (not for me) http://www.appbrain.com/app/shootme-%28screen-grabber%29/com.bw.picme.local

Comment: Have you tried ShootMe for other screens besides maps?

Comment: I cannot start the application. I says that the phone is not rooted. And I was so happy when lots of users reported that it works on un-rooted phone for them.

Answer (score 3):

Try **[Map It!](https://www.appbrain.com/app/map-it-ad-supported/com.androgone.mapit.admob)**

It won't let you send anything from the Maps App, but the Map It! app uses Google Maps and lets you draw routes and put push pins into the map, then take a screenshot of it and send it via email or MMS.

It's useful if you want to send a picture of a particular place on a map or some kind of mock up to a map, but it's no good if you're trying to send the route that you already mapped out in the separate Maps app.  To do this, I believe, you'd have to draw the route by hand on the map in Map It.

Also, you should note that it puts an ad at the top of the screen (in the same way other apps do this), and when you take your screenshot, it will show that ad too.  There is an [Ad Free version](https://www.appbrain.com/app/map-it-ad-free/com.androgone.mapit) that I haven't tried.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Yes.  I should have specified.

Comment: I wanted really just a screen shot of a map with a pin :-) But I cannot make it send via MMS. Email without any problem. When I choose Send from the menu then MMS then I get "Complete action using" menu with no mms option in there.

Comment: That's weird, it brings me right to Handcent.  I really wish they'd incorperate that into Google maps but good luck getting them to do it.  You'll probably have better luck email the dev of Map It and getting him to fix the problem.