# How to print screen my application in android phone?

Tags: screenshots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take a screenshot with an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-phone)

How to print screen my application in android phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an app called **ShootMe** from the Market to do this easily (requires root).  You can also use the Android SDK to do it without root, but you have to be connected to your computer.

Comment: How about a link?

Comment: @Al Posted this just before the web market went live, I think.  Feel free to add the link if you want.

Answer (score 7):

in the android sdk is a tool called DDMS, it will allow you to take screenshots. theres also apps on the market that can do this, but I think they require root.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Samsung Galaxy S, press the back key and keep it pressed, and then press the home key and release them both.

This will take a screenshot.

It works without rooting, without external applications, and even if the screen is locked.

Comment: Awesome. Is this something Samsung implemented themselves and is not available in other phones?

Comment: @Slavo Yep, it's part of TouchWiz.

Answer (score 1):

Ice Cream Sandwich has this built in, I believe. On my Galaxy Nexus, I hold down Power + Volume-Down, no matter what's on the screen. (It can even be at the lock screen.)

Comment: Unfortunately this does **not** work for me on a generic 7inch tablet (DGM T-703) with ICS (Android 4.0.3)

Answer (score 1):

In Cyanogenmod (7) you can press the power button to get to menu. There you can choose to take a screenshot. The screenshot is taken and it goes to same folder as photos taken by camera.

Answer (score 1):

For a Samsung Galaxy Y press the menu button and the power button at the same time to take a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the app [AndroSS](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.tedstein.AndroSS&feature=search_result).  It requires root access.  It's options include:

- Choose between .png and two different compressions of .jpg
- Choose whether you want to use the hardware camera button or shake the phone in order to take screenshots
- Choose how you want to be notified that the screenshot was taken (toast popup, sound, or vibrate)
- Choose whether you want it to remain active until you manually disable it or if it should disable itself after one screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

For Samsung Galaxy FIT press Home + Power at the same time and release. The image will save in Gallery->screenCapture.