# How do I take a screenshot on a Honeycomb tablet?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, screenshots, 3.0-honeycomb

Is there a built-in mechanism to take a screenshot on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1?  Or is there an app I can download to do so (without rooting the device)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that straight Honeycomb (Xoom, Samsung 10.1, etc) devices have the ability to take a screenshot without some help.

If you have the SDK downloaded you are able to plugin your device and take screenshots using your computer.  However, that sounds really inconvenient. Instructions can be found here under "Debugging Tips" http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html

There was also an independent app released on XDA for Honeycomb devices called Screenshot ER.  One caveat, it does require root.  http://www.xda-developers.com/android/take-screenshots-of-your-honeycomb-device-with-screenshot-er/

Market link at https://market.android.com/details?id=fahrbot.apps.screen&feature=search_result

Answer (score 3):

Partially stolen from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9119/how-do-i-perform-a-print-screen-on-a-galaxy-ace/9123#9123) (and here's [third party confirmation](http://www.thegalaxytabforum.com/index.php?/topic/413-how-to-take-screenshots-on-galaxy-tab/)):

Hold the <kbd>Back</kbd> button and tap the <kbd>Home</kbd> button (or, if that doesn't work, tap both at the same time).  This is part of Samsung's TouchWiz interface, it doesn't work on other devices.

On most other devices, the only way to take a screenshot without rooting is to use [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  You would connect your phone to your PC via USB, run `ddms`, select your phone, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: The soft buttons in the bar at the bottom?  I don't think that works, unless I'm not looking in the right place for the screenshot.  Would it be in the Gallary app?

Comment: @Daryl I believe so. I don't have TouchWiz on my Galaxy S at the moment so I can't check.

Comment: Perhaps that only works on Samsung phones (and maybe the 7" Galaxy Tab).

Comment: @Daryl Ah, I just read that it doesn't have TouchWiz.  That explains it.