# HTC Sensation sent screenshot to Google+ Instant Upload?

Tags: screenshots, google-plus, htc-sensation

I got a notification on Google+ this morning showing a screenshot of my HTC Sensation's home screen.

I checked my phone, and in the 'Camera Shots' album, there is the same picture.

I never actioned a screenshot to be taken, and didn't know my phone even took screenshots!

Why and how has this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the recent HTC phones can [take screenshots if you press <kbd>Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd>](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-phone/14166#14166) at the same time, that may be what you're doing by accident.

As previously stated, the Google+ app by default backs up your pictures to a (private) online album for easier sharing. This can be turned off entirely, or configured to only sync on wifi (to save your data allowance) and give you a chance to delete unwanted pictures before they're uploaded.

Comment: cheers @GAThrawn! I asked someone before if my phone can take screenshots and I got told its not possible, brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You obviously took a screenshot by accident. Since you also have Google+ installed, all pictures that are saved on a special place (in this case the 'Camera Shots' album) are automatically uploaded to your Google+ album, but not published.

You can turn off auto upload of pictures in the settings from the Google+ App.

Comment: or he could kill the `ScreenCaptureService`

Comment: I didn't even know the phone took screen shots. How did I accidentally take it?