# How to take a screenshot on a Kindle Fire?

Tags: screenshots, amazon-kindle-fire

I ran across this question [posed on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/anildash/status/136576313434710017) by [Anil Dash](http://stackexchange.com/users/95824/anildash):

*Is there really no way to take a screenshot on a Kindle Fire? Huh.*

I know it's early to tell, but does anyone know if this is true about the device?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me. Until recently it was rare for an Android device to offer a way to take a screen shot without rooting it.

Comment: For what its worth, the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (with most recent stock software update) allows you to take screenshots (without being rooted). So, I think pre-ICS it's possible...at least in Honeycomb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take screen shots with ddms and the Android SDK. It's not hard to set up. See http://www.thefireblog.com/2011/11/16/houston-we-have-screenshots/:

> So, here’s a quick summary people:
>
> - Install the android SDK tools, then the platform-tools
> - Edit your adb_usb.ini file to add the 0×1949 vendor ID at the end
> - Ensure that adb is running properly
> - Check that your device is online
> - Run ddms
> - Start taking your screenshots using the Device > Screen Capture option.

Comment: Very cool that this doesn't require root, +1.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

[How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-phone)

Basically Android doesn't provide you a direct way to take a screenshot the way iOS does. But Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich will.

Comment: Yes, except the Fire will not be getting ICS. It's Android under the hood, but they forked it a long time ago and Amazon will be updating it going forward.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested since I don't have my Fire yet, but [it can be rooted with SuperOneClick](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device), which means you can probably take screenshots with an app like [ShootMe](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bw.picme.local) or [Screenshot ER 2](https://market.android.com/details?id=fahrbot.apps.screen.pro1).

I would think Amazon would advertise it if it could take screenshots without root, so I would suspect non-root users to be out of luck.  That said, ShootMe has been known to work on some unrooted phones.  Nobody knows why, but you could try it and hope :P