# How can I take a screenshot on a Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: screenshots, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I thought that ICS, which is the underlying OS version for a Kindle Fire HD, supported a standard way of taking screenshots by holding down power button + volume down key. This does not work for me. Can someone confirm whether this is indeed the case or whether I'm just being slow in not holding down the buttons at the same time?

Comment: Supposedly it does support this: http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx1TD8HXMJ3BO49

Comment: Solutions for the original Fire: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15675/1465

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was hard to take screenshots on 1st generation Kindle Fire tablet. You had to Android SDK etc and connect to your computer etc just to take a screenshot. We are used to Print Screen function on computers.

How to take screenshot of Kindle Fire HD or Kindle Fire 2
1. Press and hold Volume Down & Power buttons simultaneously. Your Kindle Fire screen flickers and takes a snapshot of tablet screen.

1. You can find the saved screenshot images in Photos > Screenshots. Make sure to select Device tab at the top as shown below.

You can send saved screenshot via email, skype etc. I did not any option to send them via Bluetooth. It seems Kindle Fire has limited sharing options.

Comment: This does not work for me even if I hold it down at the same time maybe I don't have a kindle fire hd but I know I have a kindle fire because when I am powering my tablet on it says kindle fire and I know my tablet is a 2016 version because I got it for Christmas.