# Taking a screenshot in ICS without rooting

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is it possible to take a screenshot in ICS (Galaxy Nexus) without external apps and without rooting? Most apps on the market seem to require rooted phones.

I did find [this app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot) which claims to not require the phone to be rooted but it costs $4.99 which is a bit steep for an app that only takes screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press the `Volume Down` and `Power` buttons at the same time and hold them for a second or so (this is the vanilla behavior, at least; [source](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57343803-285/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-the-galaxy-nexus/)).

By default on my device it will save to `/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots` (or whatever your equivalent "external storage" path is, I assume).

Comment: Crazy ... it works from the lock screen, too; so if you find a locked phone and don't value your time, you can fill up the phone's storage with screenshots of the lock screen ...

Comment: It says that it took a screenshot, there's a file in "My Computer\Galaxy Nexus\Internal Storage\Pictures\Screenshots", but it's 0 bytes, and when I double-click on it, it says "Invalid File". Is there a third-party no-brainer product that takes screenshots? Thank you.

Comment: @Gulbahar: [How to take a screenshot with an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1759) That has pretty much all of the screenshot solutions that I'm personally aware of.