# How can I log in as root to take the screen shot?

Tags: screenshots, root-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean)
>   [How to take a screenshot with an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-phone)

I have android gingerbread. I wanted screen shots of my menu screen, so I downloaded the application from the android store,but every application wants a root access. How can I login as root so that I am able to take the screen shots just by shaking the phone?

Comment: Unlike linux, to root any device, you need to replace the kernel files to have system folder access. Check this link out: [How to Root my Device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device)

Comment: If you have a specific question about how to root your device then feel free to ask, but first you may want to look at the linked questions to see exactly what "rooting" means (and other screenshot options). Also be aware that you'll want to specify your device and Android version if you have questions about rooting it, as it can vary greatly.