# How can I screenshot the Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7, screenshots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device)

I want t take a screenshot on my Nexus 7, but none of the apps work.

How can I take a screenshot on my Nexus?

Comment: the first link in google shows (video!) how to do that...

Comment: Liam, you don't need an app for that. The linked "duplicate" a.o. points out: ***If you have Android 4.0+:** You can press the Power button + the Volume Down button at the same time to take a screenshot. It will be saved to your gallery.* Doesn't that work for you? No 3rd party app required. The Nexus 4 is, in general, an Android device -- and this is no feature "specific" to the N4.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the stock ROM, you can simultaneously hold the power and volume down buttons for 1-2 seconds. A screenshot will be captured.

If you aren't using stock, you should check the ROM's power menu (hold down the power button).