# How to sync non-picasa folder displayed in Gallery app?

Tags: sync, photos, gallery

I often use Instagram to add effect and frame to my photos.

Then, there is a folder named instagram appearing in Gallery; but that folder won't be synced with my Google account i.e. on another Android device signed in with the same account, I don't see that folder.

So my question is that how I can have it synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhotoSync (Sync to Picasa)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zehai.photosync) might be your choice:

> PhotoSync is tool for sync photos to Picasa(Google Photos). though limited, you can sync videos too.You can also sync photos among multi devices via Picasa.

[image: PhotoSync sources]

Comment: This works nice for me. Bi-directional sync available only in paid version though

Comment: Just out of topic quick ask, how would you snapshot your phone? I cannot do that without rooting it :(

Comment: That depends on the Android version running on the device. Since 4.0 it's natively built-in, before some devices (e.g. Samsung) already had it. See: [How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/16575) for examples ;) But most of the screenshots I post here come from the playstore -- I cannot install all apps on my devices just to post them :)

Answer (score 1):

The gallery is showing the Instagram folder cause it scans the whole device and external storages and grab all folders with images. You can't sync that folder but can share once in a while with Picasa so that process will upload images on that folder to Picasa. And then Picasa will sync that folder to your rest of the devices.

Comment: How can I share `once in a while` that Instagram folder JanithaR? I tried to upload it to Picasa but I'm afraid it just create a new album and not synced at all

Comment: Just select the whole folder (tap and wait), the share option will popup and chose Picasa. The first time tell Picasa to create a new folder and it will create Instagram folder and upload the files to it. The next time when you have new files to upload simply share again and that time chose the existing Instagram folder in Picasa. :) You can't automate this unless of course there is a third party app built for it.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and helpful explanation! I need it automated though.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at apps like e.g. [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite):

> FolderSync is a application that enables simple sync to cloud based storage to and from local folders on the device memory card. It currently support multiple SkyDrive, Dropbox, SugarSync, Ubuntu One, Box.net, LiveDrive, HiDrive, Google Docs, NetDocuments, Amazon S3, FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WebDAV or windows share (Samba/CIFS) accounts, and support for more platforms are planned.

With this app you can define which folders shall be synced where, thus adapting everything to your very convenience.

[image: FolderSync Cloud support] [image: FolderSync synchronization pairs]
<sup>(click images to enlarge; source: Google Play)</sup>

Comment: Would be lovely and meet my need if `FolderSync` have the `Picasa` name on the list. Thanks Izzy!

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't sync directly to Picasa, it seems. But you might ask the dev, maybe he adds it. As long as it's not there, you can still use it to sync the images across devices. Or take a look at [PhotoSync (Sync to Picasa)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zehai.photosync).

Comment: Please separate your answer for PhotoSync as a new answer so as to be accepted. Thanks for your help Izzy.

Comment: As you wish ;-)