# Taking Screenshots in Micromax Ninja A89 ICS Mobile Device

Tags: screenshots

I have a new Micromax Ninja A89 Mobile phone which is not rooted. I want to be able to take screenshots in my mobile without rooting. What should I do? I have tried many of the freely available apps but they are not working.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: your question already got answered here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device - the answer considers all variant (root/non-root, ics etc.) - the most reliable way is always by using the android sdk and using ddms

Answer (score 1):

Hold the volume down and power button together. That will take a screenshot.