# How to take screenshot with stock Samung Galaxy S4 from Google Play Store

Tags: stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s-4, screenshots

I have a stock Samsung Galaxy S4 fresh from the Google Play Store, and I can't get this phone to take a screen shot using the <kbd>power</kbd> and <kbd>home</kbd> button method. Without using an app, what else should I try to fix the problem?

Comment: Try volume down + power button (you need to press them at the exact same time, otherwise it won't work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device)

Comment: Afraid that's not working for me either I just get my volume lowered and my home screen

Comment: If you got your home screen, were you pressing volume down + home? It's volume down + power.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say Google now. I use it enough to call it home :) and yes I am sure it was volume down and home

Comment: What Dan was trying to point out is that volume down + home is *not* the button combination that the first comment suggested. It's volume down + the power button. If you are pressing the home button on the front of the device then you're using the wrong button combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try (volume down + power button). You need to press them at the exact same time, otherwise it won't work. Also make sure you hold it down for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to take a screenshot without an app according to [this](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-galaxy-s3-note-2-android/) article.

1. Open Settings -> Motion
2. Scroll down to *Hand motion*
3. Enable *Palm swipe to capture*

Comment: That does not apply to the Stock version from the Play store.