# alternative ways to take screenshots on Galaxy

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, screenshots

When there is a rubber-protector around the phone or the tablet, I find it extremely difficult to do a palm-swipe-to-capture action,  to get a screenshot.

That's due to the fact that the raised edges of the screen protector prevents my palm to completely flush on the surface of the phone.

Is there a way to get the screenshot any other way and a more convenient way? 
Or an app that will do that? matye thru share via route??

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device has 16 answers. I would assume at least one will be usable.

Comment: Volume down and power button, or else home button and volume button. That's how most galaxy phones work, but a google of it shows tons of videos and descriptions for each Note model