# I can not screenshot on my samsung galaxymini s~3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung

How  do i screenshot on samsung galaxy s~3 
Model number GT-S5280
Android Version4.1.2

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device

Answer (score 1):

Press `Power` and `Home` buttons at the same time.
You will see a white effect, and then, the screenshot is ready to share through a notification.