# Screenshot on a Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: screenshots, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I saw a couple places online saying you can hit the power button (on the side) and the home button (on the front, at the bottom) together on the S5, similar to the way you take a screenshot on an iPhone.  However, it doesn't seem to be working with the S6.  Can anyone explain the process for getting a screenshot on a Samsung Galaxy S6?

Comment: Are you pressing them simultaneously for 1-2 seconds? The official website mentioned the same procedure, but an another one too which uses a gesture. See http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00038721/746369734/

Comment: Have you tried standard android shortcut: power button + volume down?

Comment: @Firelord - OK, that worked.  Although it's still a bit tricky to get the timing down.  The iPhone was a little more lenient in terms of timing the button pushes.  I'll get used to it eventually, I'm sure.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device)

Answer (score -1):

on Samsung s6 you can swap your palm over the screen to take a screenshot