# How to Auto-upload Screenshots of Android to Google Photos or Other?

Tags: oneplus-3, google-photos, oneplus-two, oxygenos

I just noticed that my phone is not automatically uploading screenshots into Google Photos.

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: OxygenOS 3.1 (Android 6.x)

Phone: Oneplus 3T
OS: Oreo 8.0

Comment: [use Google Now](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/146403/131553)

Comment: AFAIK , auto uploaded to Google photos is not a standard feature of stock. I am not aware of Oxygen. I suggested Google Now since it shows the option of Google photos amongst a bunch of others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Photos and enable *Back & Sync* for the feature.

Differential solution.
Use Mega where you can enable Auto-upload of pictures/camera shots to the application.

OS: Oreo 8.0
Phone: Oneplus 3T

Answer (score 0):

Auto-upload of Screenshots is not a standard feature in Android 6.x at the moment. (beeshyams)