# Unable to take screenshot on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s7

If I swipe with the edge of a palm, it is very unreliable -- sometimes screen is pressed and I do some operations instead of screen shot.

Pressing `Home` + `Power` simultaneously doesn't work.

What else can be done?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to take screenshow of an application, which I am debugging. When I run debug, it requests to close device monitor, so the third way of taking screenshots via device monitor also doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**

Disabling swipe didn't help. Now it is impossible to take screenshot from within device at all.

Comment: Press POWER a wee bit earlier than HOME.

Comment: Descibes 3 steps here : http://www.androidcentral.com/how-take-screenshot-samsung-galaxy-s7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device)

Comment: @AndyYan doesn't work

Comment: Did you see the Google Now option in the answer linked as possible duplicate above?

Comment: You can use `adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png`

Answer (score 0):

If taking a screenshot with hardware keys don't so seem to work for you, you can use gestures to take a screenshot instead:

1. Activate gestures: go to Settings > Motions.
2. Inside the Motion menu, look for Hand Motions.
3. Check the Palm Swipe to capture.

[image: IMG:]

Once you have activated the gesture, you can now grab a screenshot:

- Go to the screen that you want to take a screenshot of.
- Now swipe the edge of your hand from right to left and vice versa, horizontally.

This edge-to-edge swipe gesture may take you a few tries to master, but it makes taking screenshots so much easier and quicker.

Comment: In words, this feature sounds great.  Unfortunately, I have only been able to get it actually work about 1 in 10 times.  Similar problem with Samsung's "shake to turn on the flashlight" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your toggle notification, maybe you have an option to trigger screenshoot, or you can use a third party app for that, that enables you maybe a notification icon that when you press, one screenshoot is taken.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same problem and for me this worked:

Pressing <kbd>Volume down</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

But unfortunately, it looks as if Android does not make screenshots when the phone is locked. This is no problem on the iPhone.

Samsung S7, Android 8.0.0