# Direct HDMI output at the start up?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb, hdmi

I have an Android 6.0.1 Vibe P1 Turbo with literally dead screen(I closed the phone months ago and did a complete disassembly).

What I want to do is get the phone output the screen through USB right when it starts up. I was thinking about octopus micro USB with USB A legs and attach both a mouse and an "USB to HDMI converter" to connect it to the dumb LCD TV (1366X768 PAL) and backup data to the Google Drive and shut down the phone for good.

Will I be able to do it? Or I have to open the phone first which makes it impossible? Can you give me an things to have and a tutorial?

The phone has pattern lock

Comment: Is the device encrypted? Is a pattern/PIN/password set? Does it connect to Wifi if you boot it up? If yes, does the last seen date of the device in Google Play Store update?

Comment: Encrypted? I am not CIA the pattern is sadly sent (Altought the screen is really fucked up (Vertical streaks with more colors in a rainbow) I remember the touchscreen working so I guess I think I can open it. I completely disassembled the phone so I guess it will take some to reassemble it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB to HDMI converters require special driver. I never heard of an Android device supporting such a converter. The typical way to connect a Android device to a TV is using Wifi and screen cast technology.

There are some device that support MHL (re-use the USB-Port for a HDMI connection) but the number of device that support this is not very high and depends on the used chip in the phone. Anyway the USB port would be blocked in such a case and can't be used for USB devices.

Edit: Based on the additional info your provided (unlock possible, touch still works) the following may work:

1. Unlock the phone and connect it via USB to a PC. You should get access to your sd-card folder.
2. Use the [screenshot feature](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1773/2241) to get the current screen content.
3. Open the screenshot on the connected PC
4. Try to tap on the position of the function you want to execute
5. Goto step 2

Using this you should be able to "use" your device in a very very basic way. Therefore what ever you want to to with it (e.g. exporting data)  might be possible this way.

Comment: Peh. looks like I got too used  to my good ole N8 with HDMI.

Comment: @Jonathan see my edit

Comment: thanks ! I never thought a comment could change so much things!

Comment: even though  my phone is such an asshole it has tendency not to show files sometimes and the volume and power buttons are ripped off in the cable level